# Twig: How to access multiple values from node reference field with number_format

Tags: 8, theming

I'm adding fields to array:

```
{% for item in content.field_notes | field_target_entity %}
   {% set field_component_pages = item.field_component_pages|view|number_format %} 
{% endfor %}
```

In my scenario the value of item.field_component_pages|view is equal "16", but when I convert it to number with number_format I get value of 1.

I presume the `item.field_component_pages|view` is not a real value. How can I access field field_component_pages correctly in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it form the value. something like `item.field_component_pages.0.value` properly works for you

```
{% for item in content.field_notes | field_target_entity %}
   {% set field_component_pages = item.field_component_pages.0.value|number_format %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The output is  Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in and returns 0

Comment: @adpo can you please tell me what is the response of {{ dump(item.field_component_pages) }}

Comment: @adpo , ok , then try {{ dump(item.field_component_pages|view) }}

Comment: @adpo would you please share a screenshot of  this fields ( while you are not able to dump it) . I should know the type and field settings somehow

Comment: @yosef Thank you for you support. I have decided to dump this value from hook_preprocess_node. and tthe correct value is item.field_component_pages.0.value

Comment: @adpo you're welcome. I've updated the question base on your solution. maybe it will be helpful for another guy in the future. :)